# How to Autologin, then lock

Tags: login

I want to be able to have my computer log me in automatically, then immediatly lock my screen. I have Ubuntu 12.10 and my home folder is encrypted. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

To lock your screen. Adding this to your start-up applications would lock on log in.